# KDB/q count number of rows group by value of a column

Tags: kdb

I have a table like following

```
tickTime    secid   ltp
1.28E+18    37991   7350
1.28E+18    38596   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    38596   7350
1.28E+18    37986   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    37981   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    45402   7350
1.28E+18    37981   7350
```

How can I do a count of no of rows for each secid in Q ?
Something like select count(*) group by secid in sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select count i by secid from tablename
```

This is how you create a count column. It will return the secid's and the number of times they occur in a table. Could rename the count column to "counts" as follows:

```
select counts:count i by secid from tablename
```